# BeautifulSoup returning only one result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm learning how to scrape data from an HTML. I suppose to get 16 results. however, it only appears one. Can you please help me and let me know where I get it wrong? 
I'm sorry if this question may have bugged the experienced. I've just learnt how to code and this is my very first question.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_url(url):
    """Get parsed HTML from url
      Input: url to the webpage
      Output: Parsed HTML text of the webpage
    """
    # Send GET request
    r = requests.get("https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789?src=c.1789.hamburger_menu_fly_out_banner&_lc=Vk4wMzkwMTUwMDk=")

    # Parse HTML text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    return soup

def scrape_tiki(url="https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789?src=c.1789.hamburger_menu_fly_out_banner&_lc=Vk4wMzkwMTUwMDk="):

    # Get parsed HTML
    soup = get_url(url)

    products = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'product-item'})

    data = []

    for product in products:
      d = {'title':'','image':'','productID':'','sellerID':'', 'price':''}

    try:
      d['title'] = product['data-title']
      d['productID'] = product['product-sku']
      d['sellerID'] = product['data-seller-product-id']
      d['price'] = product['data-price']

      if product.img:
        d['image'] = product.span.img['src']

      data.append(d)
    except:

      pass
    return data
```

````
data```


This is the result I received. 



```[{'image': 'https://salt.tikicdn.com/cache/280x280/ts/product/8b/05/5c/fd6a3d0311b6a76e51dde3d483a499ba.jpg',
  'price': '8075000',
  'productID': '2171294279484',
  'sellerID': '51051164',
  'title': 'Điện Thoại Samsung Galaxy A71 (128GB/8GB) - Hàng Chính Hãng - Đã Kích Hoạt Bảo Hành Điện Tử'}]```
````

Comment: The indentation of `try..except` block is wrong. Move it one level right.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation in the for loop is returning only one result in the `for product in products:` this fix will return all divs that from class product-item

```
for product in products:
    d = {}
    try:
      d['title'] = product['data-title']
      d['productID'] = product['product-sku']
      d['sellerID'] = product['data-seller-product-id']
      d['price'] = product['data-price']

      if product.img:
        d['image'] = product.span.img['src']

      data.append(d)
    except:    
      pass
return data
```

Comment: you can chnage `d = {'title':'','image':'','productID':'','sellerID':'', 'price':''}` to this `d = {}`